# unable to access hostname in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ip-address, hostname

My vagrant file looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|  
  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-7.0"  

#cent71 will be the server  
  config.vm.define :cent71 do |cent71|  
    cent71.vm.hostname = "cent71.nv.server"  
    cent71.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.70.101"  
  end  
end
```

While I am able to access 192.168.70.101:8080 on my host machine's web browser, I am unable to access it via cent71.nv.server:8080
What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an entry to your host machine's /etc/hosts file(I make the assumption you're using a mac or linux machine, no clue what to do on windows).

It should look something like the following.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

# your mapping right here
192.168.70.101       cent71.nv.server
```